# Why can't I use .call() in a replace function?

Tags: javascript, reference, replace, call

Why is this valid:

```
function func(a,b,c) {
    console.log(this, a,b,c);
    return '';
}
'testing'.replace(/e/, func);
```

but this isn't:

```
function func(a,b,c) {
    console.log(this, a,b,c);
    return '';
}
'testing'.replace(/e/, func.call);
```

if func is a function reference, and call is a function reference shouldn't they both work?

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxqT7/)** of this

Comment: It is an object, not a function reference

Comment: @Caspar — `typeof (function () { }).call` is "function"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you pass the `call` function, you take it out of the context of `func`, so inside `call` the `this` keyword will refer to `window` instead of `func`.

`window` is not a function, but `call` expects `this` to be a function, so it breaks.

For comparison.

```
var AnObject = {
    call: function () { console.log("this.location is: ", this.location); },
    location: "This string is the location property of AnObject"
};

AnObject.call();
setTimeout(AnObject.call, 500);
```

Comment: can you elaborate? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: shouldn't call's first argument be the matched char, so then the `this` in func would then be `'e'`

Comment: @qwertmk — Since it is calling `window.call` and not `func.call`, that would just try to `window('e')` which wouldn't help.

Comment: this might get many upvotes, but it is not a correct answer :P

Comment: I don't get why when i pass it func it calls func() yet when i pass it func.call it doesn't call func.call() , func.call() without any args is valid so why isn't it at called then? Thanks for the answers so far I think I'm starting to get it, just need a little more push

Comment: @qwertymk — Because it calls the thing you pass — and you pass the function, not the function combined with the object that you got it from.

Comment: So then how does `call()` know which function to execute?

Comment: `call` knows what function to execute, because it executes `this`. Normally you do `something.call()` and `this` is something. When you call `call` by itself, the `something` is automatically `window`.

Comment: No, that shouldn't work. Passing a reference to a function passes **just** the reference to the function, it doesn't matter how many levels of other objects you go through to get it.

Comment: Given `{ foo: { bar: { baz: 7 } } }` then `foo.bar.baz` is `7` and if I call `alert(foo.bar.baz)` then the `alert` function gets `7` as the argument. The fact I got the `7` from `foo.bar.baz` is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: oh functions passed as arguments gets passed by value and not by reference. And the value of the call function depends on the context which changed because it doesn't know it's own `this` and therefore tries but can't execute `window()` . Is that right?

Comment: meaning that when I pass a function as an argument to a different function like `console.log(jQuery)` it really does `console.log((new Function(jQuery.toString()))` in essence (obviously not for native functions)

Comment: No. It passes the function itself. It just doesn't pass the context that the function is in. If you add a property to the function, that property is available in both places you can access to it. The meaning of `this` inside a function is all about how a function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.call()` itself is a method, but not one that is useful to `replace()`.

In other words, while your intention is to pass `func`,  you're actually passing a completely different function (`call`) that serves a purpose not useful as an argument to `.replace()`.

Comment: forget the arguments, I just want to know why it breaks

Comment: @qwertymk: Ok fine, I forgot the arguments. Why does it surprise you that passing an unrelated function as an argument doesn't work? There are plenty of functions that could be passed that would break because they're not being used in their intended manner.

Comment: call is just a method of func so it should still be called, no? And it's not like anything in func can hurt the string, all it cares about is the return value

Comment: *"...call is just a method of func..."* No. You've removed `func` from the equation when you decided to pass `call` to `replace` instead. The `call` method is not somehow inextricably bound to your function. The `call` method relies on there being a function to the left of it. When you pass `func.call`, you're not actually passing `func.call`. You're just passing `call`. You just happen to be referencing it via `func`.

Comment: @qwertymk: By the way, in some newer implementations, there is a `.bind()` method that can be used to bind a context to a function. If you do this... `func.call.bind(func)` ...in Chrome, it will work since `call` will be pre-bound to `func`. When `replace()` invokes it, it will be the same as if you did `func.call`.